# WP_Query Alter archive page Query

Tags: wordpress, meta-key

I have a scenario where i want to get featured property first then other properties which are not featured. I have saved a meta_key with _property_featured with 1 if the property is featured.
For this i'm using **pre_get_posts** hook, here is the code

```
      function my_property_modify_query( $query ) {
         if ( is_post_type_archive('property') || is_tax('property_contracts')) {
             set_query_var( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
             set_query_var( 'meta_key', '_property_featured' );
             set_query_var( 'ORDER', 'DESC' );
         }
      }
      add_action( "pre_get_posts", "my_property_modify_query" );
```

but it only shows featured property any suggestion why is he doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to put the meta_key before the orderby parameter.
And I think you don't need to use meta_value_num since 1 is just a flag and the the ordering will give you some strange results.

Comment: I have fixed it, basically in the wp_postmeta when my post is saving if featured checkbox is checked it save _property_featured by 1 otherwise it removed _property_featured meta_key so thats why its showing only the featured property. Now i have saved _property_featured by 0 also and it works !

Comment: Okay good, so it was showing only them because the other posts didn't have the meta.